# Is it possible to have one onlick run different functions one after the other in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to make one of those DO NOT PRESS THE RED BUTTON games for class and basically I need to display text on top of the red button.
Problem is you don't only press the red button once so I'm having trouble with making it work.
I was thinking of making a click counter and using that as basis for an if-else statement.
For example, if(clicks == 0 ) I want the paragraph IDed ButtonText to be "Press me!" at clicks = 1, I want the text to be "Hi!" at clicks = 2, I want to be "Hello." Can someone help me please?
Here's what I have so far including the css and the hypothetical if else statement:

```js
var clicks = 0;
function myFunction() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = clicks;
};

/*  
function Function() {
    if(clicks == 0) {
        document.getElementById("ButtonText").innerHTML = "Press Me!"
    }
    if else(clicks == 1) {
        document.getElementById("ButtonText").innerHTML = "Hi"
    }
    else(clicks == 2) {
        document.getElementById("ButtonText").innerHTML = "Hello."
    }
} 
*/
```

```css
div {
    font: Arial;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 13% 0 0 38%;
    font-size: 58px;
    color: white;
    width: 380px;
    height: 480px;
    border: 0px black transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

p {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}

#button {
    display: block;
    width: 665px;
    height: 665px;
    background: url(Images/Unpressed.jpg) no-repeat top;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
 
#button:active {
    background: url(Images/Pressed.jpg) no-repeat bottom;
}
```

```html
<p>Clicks: <p id="counter">0</p></p>
<div id="container" onclick="myFunction()">
    <p id="ButtonText">Press Me!</p>
</div>
<a id="button" onClick="myFunction()"></a>
```

Comment: Voting to close this as "Too Broad" as there are too many possible answers (other than the simple Yes). Consider using google to find a tutorial or narrow down your question to focus on specific details you're having problems with.

Comment: Or How do you do it?

Comment: Call the second function from the first. Or just say `onclick="firstFunc(); secondFunc(); thirdFunc(); etc();"`.

Comment: Agree with @zzzzBov, this more of a simple code logic rather than a JS question. . Meanwhile here is a sample working code for OP just in case he finds this too tough. I used `data-` attribute to solve this but can be done via a global variable also. https://jsfiddle.net/154fqkqm/

Answer (score 2):

You are close.  There are some syntax errors in your javascript.  `if else()` is not valid and should be `else if()`.  F12 will show you errors like these in the browser console.  Also pay attention to where your brackets and indents are to help with code readability.

Aside from that, just use an event listener to call the function that checks the click value.  Something like this would work:

```
var clicks = 0;
function myFunction() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = clicks;

};

function foo(){
    myFunction();
    if(clicks == 0){
        document.getElementById("ButtonText").innerHTML = "Press Me!";
    } else if (clicks == 1) {
        document.getElementById("ButtonText").innerHTML = "Hi";
    } else if (clicks == 2) {
        document.getElementById("ButtonText").innerHTML = "Hello.";
    } else {
        //more than 3 clicks
    }

}

//add an event listener to your button
document.getElementById('ButtonText').addEventListener('click',foo);
```

Here it is in a JS Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/bbtawaff/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Adam! I tried plugging it into my code but it still doesn't work. the counter still works but there is no text displayed.

Comment: Is it possible that the `color` of your text is white on a white background?

Comment: @Anthony nope. I tried changing the color to black before commenting. No text at all.

Answer (score 2):

```js
    var clicks = 0;
    var clicks = 0;
  
 function myFunction() {

        clicks += 1;
        var greetings= ["hi","hello","Press Me!"]; 
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = clicks;
        document.getElementById("ButtonText").innerHTML = greetings[clicks % greetings.length];

    };



 
 /*function Function(){
 if(clicks == 0){
 document.getElementById("ButtonText").innerHTML = "Press Me!"}
 if else(clicks == 1){
 document.getElementById("ButtonText").innerHTML = "Hi"}
 else(clicks == 2){
 document.getElementById("ButtonText").innerHTML = "Hello."}
    } */
```

```css
 div{
 font: Arial;
 position: fixed;
 margin: 13% 0 0 38%;
 font-size: 58px;
 color: white;
 width: 380px;
 height: 480px;
 border: 0px black transparent;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

 p{
 cursor: pointer;
 display: block;}

 #button {
 display: block;
 width: 665px;
 height: 665px;
 background: url(Images/Unpressed.jpg) no-repeat top;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-left: 30%;
 margin-top: 10%;
 }
 
 #button:active {
 background: url(Images/Pressed.jpg) no-repeat bottom;
 }
```

```html
 <p>Clicks: <p id="counter">0</p></p>
 <div id="container" onclick="myFunction()"><p id="ButtonText">Press Me!</p></div>
 <a id="button" onClick="myFunction()"></a>
```

```js
    var clicks = 0;
 function myFunction() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = clicks;

    };
 
 /*function Function(){
 if(clicks == 0){
 document.getElementById("ButtonText").innerHTML = "Press Me!"}
 if else(clicks == 1){
 document.getElementById("ButtonText").innerHTML = "Hi"}
 else(clicks == 2){
 document.getElementById("ButtonText").innerHTML = "Hello."}
    } */
```

```css
 div{
 font: Arial;
 position: fixed;
 margin: 13% 0 0 38%;
 font-size: 58px;
 color: white;
 width: 380px;
 height: 480px;
 border: 0px black transparent;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

 p{
 cursor: pointer;
 display: block;}

 #button {
 display: block;
 width: 665px;
 height: 665px;
 background: url(Images/Unpressed.jpg) no-repeat top;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-left: 30%;
 margin-top: 10%;
 }
 
 #button:active {
 background: url(Images/Pressed.jpg) no-repeat bottom;
 }
```

```html
 <p>Clicks: <p id="counter">0</p></p>
 <div id="container" onclick="myFunction()"><p id="ButtonText">Press Me!</p></div>
 <a id="button" onClick="myFunction()"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<script>
var clicks = 0;
var myFunction = function() {
  if(clicks == 0) return false // not sure if you would want to return false here, it would prevent the increment of clicks     
  if(clicks%2==0){
     document.getElementById("elementToChange").innerHTML = "new value";
   } else {
      alert('hello');
   }
    clicks += 1;
   document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = clicks;
  };
   </script>


 <div>Clicks: <p id="counter">0</p></div>


 <input type="button" id="container" onClick="myFunction();" value="clickme1"/>
```

Using the modulo (%) operator will accomplish your task

Play around with it and use the console to see what the JS does each time you click

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Answer (score 0):

See This Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/coolbhes/7yhkfqq9/

```
 var clicks = 0;
    function myFunction() {
         clicks += 1;
        var greetings= ["hi","hello","Press Me!","add As many you like..."]; 
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = clicks;
        document.getElementById("ButtonText").innerHTML = greetings[clicks % greetings.length];

    };

document.getElementById('ButtonText').addEventListener('click',myFunction);
```